# Getting a data frame from other data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

> This is my `dataframe`

```
     Date       Name  Count
0   Sep-2015    Adam    3
1   Sep-2015    David   3
2   Sep-2015    Adam    4
3   Sep-2015    Adam    3
4   Sep-2015    David   6
5   Sep-2015    Hardik  1
6   Sep-2015    David   3
```

> Now I want to unique `Name` with respect to `Date` and enter in other `dataframe`.
> I tried this

```
 df = pd.DataFrame((['Sep-2015',  'Adam',3 ],         
['Sep-2015',  'David',3],
['Sep-2015',  'Adam',4],                   
['Sep-2015',  'Adam' ,3],         
['Sep-2015',  'David',6],         
['Sep-2015' , 'Hardik',1],        
['Sep-2015' , 'David' ,3]),columns=['Date','Name','Count'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'Name'], keep='last')
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({i : [j for j in df['Count']] for i in df['Name']},index = [i for i in df['Date']])
```

> I am getting this

```
         Adam   Hardik  David
Sep-2015    3      3    3
Sep-2015    1      1    1
Sep-2015    3      3    3
```

> Here data entry is somewhere wrong. The following is the expected output.

```
           Adam   Hardik    David
Sep-2015    3        1       3
```

Answer (score 2):

After your run your `drop_duplicates()`, and you are here:

```
       Date    Name  Count
3  Sep-2015    Adam      3
5  Sep-2015  Hardik      1
6  Sep-2015   David      3
```

Try using `pd.pivot_table()` as below:

```
pd.pivot_table(df1,index='Date',columns='Name',values='Count').reset_index()
```

Which will give you:

```
Name      Date  Adam  David  Hardik
0     Sep-2015     3      3       1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a Pivot table. `pandas` already has a method for that called `pd.pivot_table`

try:

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd


# the example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame((['Sep-2015',  'Adam',3 ],         
['Sep-2015',  'David',3],
['Sep-2015',  'Adam',4],                   
['Sep-2015',  'Adam' ,3],         
['Sep-2015',  'David',6],         
['Sep-2015' , 'Hardik',1],        
['Sep-2015' , 'David' ,3]),columns=['Date','Name','Count'])

# drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'Name'], keep='last')

#pivot table
pd.pivot_table(data = df, values = 'Count', columns = 'Name', index = 'Date').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Date      Adam  David  Hardik                         
Sep-2015     3      3       1
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is coming from `index=[i for i in df['Date']]`. As soon as you are doing this, it will put a line for each component in `df['Date']` : you have three times in a row September-2015 so it will create three lines : `['Sep-2015', 'Sep-2015', 'Sep-2015']`

The second issue is coming from `{i : [j for j in df['Count']] for i in df['Name']}` which corresponds to `{'Adam': [3, 1, 3], 'Hardik': [3, 1, 3], 'David': [3, 1, 3]}`. I guess that is not what you expect.

Assuming your desired output, I guess that what you desire is : `{'Adam': [3], 'Hardik': [1], 'David': [3]}` and `['Sep-2015']`

An idea to achieve it would be to construct it beforehand, here is what I suggest :

```
a={}
for i in range(df['Name'].size):
    a[df['Name'].iloc[i]]=df['Count'].iloc[i]

dftest=pd.DataFrame (a,index = [i for i in df['Date'].drop_duplicates()])
```

Of course, the loop may be modified to manage your expectations, specifically if you have different dates in your program.